# Format errors in Go - %s %v or %w

Tags: string, go, error-handling, formatting

`%s` `%v` and `%w` can be used to format errors in Go (turn them into strings with `fmt.Errorf`).

They seem to be used differently in  Go's own tools.

In [cmd/go/internal/get/path.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1fb7d5472e8f46faaa034fe6e16ca66a1e7c766f/src/cmd/go/internal/get/path.go#L26):

`return fmt.Errorf("malformed import path %q: %v", path, err)`

In [cmd/go/internal/list/list.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6a9d850b82172225b55bd65e830b1e325b17a724/src/cmd/go/internal/list/list.go#L355):

`base.Fatalf("%s", err)`

Which format string should I use?

Answer (score 108):

> Should I use %s or %v to format errors?

**TL;DR;** Neither. Use `%w` in 99.99% of cases. In the other 0.001% of cases, `%v` and `%s` probably "should" behave the same, except when the error value is `nil`, but there are no guarantees. The friendlier output of `%v` for `nil` errors may be reason to prefer `%v` (see below).

Now for details:

### Use `%w` instead of `%v` or `%s`:

As of Go 1.13 (or earlier if you use [golang.org/x/xerrors](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/xerrors)), you can use the `%w` verb, only for `error` values, which wraps the error such that it can later be unwrapped with [`errors.Unwrap`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Unwrap), and so that it can be considered with [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) and [`errors.As`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#As).

The only times this is inappropriate:

1. You must support an older version of Go, and `xerrors` is not an option.
2. You want to create a unique error, and *not* wrap an existing one.  This might be appropriate, for instance, if you get a `Not found` error from your database when searching for a user, and want to convert this to an `Unauthorized` response. In such a case, it's rare that you'd be using the original error value with *any* formatting verb, though.

### Okay, so what about `%v` and `%s`?

The details for how `%s` and `%v` are implemented are available [in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing). I've highlighted the parts relevant to your question.

> 1. If the operand is a reflect.Value, the operand is replaced by the concrete value that it holds, and printing continues with the next rule.
> 2. **If an operand implements the Formatter interface, it will be invoked.** Formatter provides fine control of formatting.
> 3. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
>    **If the format** (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) **is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply**:
> 4. **If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked** to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. **If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked** to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

To summarize, the `fmt.*f` functions will:

1. Look for a `Format()` method, and if it exists, they'll call it.
2. Look for a `Error()` method, and if it exists, they'll call it.
3. Look for a `String()` method, and if it exists, call it.
4. Use some default formatting.

So in practice, this means that `%s` and `%v` are identical, except when a `Format()` method exists on the error type (or when the error is `nil`). When an error does have a `Format()` method, one might hope that it would produce the same output with `%s`, `%v`, and `err.Error()`, but since this is up to the implementation of the error, there are no guarantees, and thus no "right answer" here.

And finally, if your error type supports the `%+v` verb variant, then you will, of course, need to use that, if you desire the detailed output.

### `nil` values

While it's rare to (intentionally) call `fmt.*f` on a `nil` error, the behavior does differ between `%s` and `%v`:

```
%s: %!s(<nil>)
%v: <nil>
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/mZYuJof6KQY)

Answer (score 3):

Use `%v` for an error val.

```golang
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("pack %v: %v", name, err)
}
```

But, In `Go 1.13`, the `fmt.Errorf` function supports a new `%w` verb. When this verb is present, the error returned by `fmt.Errorf` will have an `Unwrap` method returning the argument of `%w`, which must be an error. In all other ways, `%w` is identical to `%v`.

```golang
if err != nil {
    // Return an error which unwraps to err.
    return fmt.Errorf("pack %v: %w", name, err)
}
```

Places where you need to differentiate between `%w` and `%v`:

*Read comments in the codeblock*

```golang
f, err := os.Open(filename)
if err != nil {
    // The *os.PathError returned by os.Open is an internal detail.
    // To avoid exposing it to the caller, repackage it as a new
    // error with the same text.
    //
    //
    // We use the %v formatting verb, since
    // %w would permit the caller to unwrap the original *os.PathError.
    return fmt.Errorf("%v", err)
}
```

Read: [For an error, when should I switch to w](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/ErrorValueFAQ#i-am-already-using-fmterrorf-with-v-or-s-to-provide-context-for-an-error-when-should-i-switch-to-w)

---

Also, the built-in error interface allows Go programmers to add whatever information they desire. All it requires is a type that implements an `Error` method

Example:

```
type QueryError struct {
    Query string
    Err   error
}

func (e *QueryError) Error() string { return e.Query + ": " + e.Err.Error() }
```

So, mostly most examples have a similar type of implementation where `err` has an `Error` method which returns `string` for which you can use `%s`