# golang how to remove %!d(string= in string

Tags: string, go, integer, format

I have this:

```golang
newStr := fmt.Sprintf("new price: %d€", newPrice)
fmt.Println(newStr) // new price:  %!d(string=500.00)€
// except I want: new price: 500,00€
```

How to remove the `%!d(` and the `)` at the end of the string so it can be like this `new price: 500,00€`

I could use a format the `strings.Replace` but I don't think it's the good answer.

My `newPrice` is a float.

I'm pretty sure it as already been ask but it's hard to google those kind of things.

Comment: `%d` denotes an integer argument; the warning is telling you that `newPrice` is a string. To fix this either use `%s` or pass in an `int`

Comment: newPrice is a float so using `%s` replace `%!d(string=` by `%!s(float64` @Brits

Comment: In your example it's a `string` (see this in [the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2bIUIQJzZ9n)). As per the answer use `%f` for floats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `%d` for an integer value in your call to `fmt.Sprintf()`, but passing a floating-point value (500,00).

Try this:

```
newStr := fmt.Sprintf("new price: %f€", newPrice)
fmt.Println(newStr)
```

Comment: thanks, I've found this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283248/format-errors-in-go-s-v-or-w  and I try differents letters, but I can't find in the doc. What are all the letters available and what does they mean

Comment: See the [fmt docs](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt)